# Can an Azure DevOps Status badge show the very latest status of the Build stage?

Tags: azure-devops

I added a Status badge for my Azure Pipeline Build stage in the readme markdown file. The badge appears but it shows the status of an older build that failed. There have been a couple of builds that ran after that which were successful. In the newer pipeline instances where the build stage has succeeded there are unfinished stages that come after the build stage.

It appears that the Status badge links to the build stage in the latest pipeline instance where all stages have either completed, been cancelled, or failed.

I would like to get a status link to the build in the very latest pipeline instance even if other pipeline stages are still pending.

Is it possible to link to a complete stage in the latest pipeline instance before all the other stages complete? If so, what URL syntax will link to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to link to a complete stage in the latest pipeline
> instance before all the other stages complete?

I am afraid that we can not get the status of the stage before all the other stages complete. The Status budge will be updated after the pipeline is completed. But this is indeed a good suggestion. I found a similar suggestion ticket in [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/406102/status-badge-doesnt-display-pipeline-as-running-st.html). You can vote and follow this ticket. You can also create a new suggestion ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21). The product group will review these tickets regularly, and consider take it as roadmap.

Comment: I think that the current developer community item covers the requirement so I have upvoted it.